# Encoding in ActionLink

Tags: html, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, encoding

I have multiple encoding/decoding problems in my source code like:

```
<li><a href="/prispevky/unia-zien" title="Únia žien">&#218;nia žien</a></li>
```

there should be

```
<li><a href="/prispevky/unia-zien" title="Únia žien">Únia žien</a></li>
```

This link is created by using `Html.ActionLink` helper, but problem is as well as with

tags. It only appears when viewing source code, on site is everything good.

Is there some way, how to handle it globally? I tried to add `Html.Raw` but it will not affect performance when call will be on multiple places over whole website? Or when I leave it as is - it is problem with SEO?

Comment: HTML entities like `&#218;` are perfect valid content on a website. So I _strongly_ doubt that this will affect SEO in any way.

Comment: Exactly what are the "problems" you are referring to?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure but you should try with

```
@Html.Raw(HttpUtility.HtmlDecode(Model.Content))
```